# AT89C2051 IC crystal and crystal oscillator connection

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, crystal

I am referring schematic for [AT89C2051](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0368.pdf) IC and 4 AT89C2051 IC's are used for motor application as shown.

(Pls note there are total 3 IC's where XTAL2 pin of first IC is assigned to XTAL1 of other 3)

[image: Case1]

Now, I want to replace crystal with crystal oscillator, IC datasheet suggests following configuration as per datasheet's page no. 4

[image: Datasheet]

So, I am thinking to add below configuration in design.

[image: Sch]

**Is it correct approach  OR I need to do some changes, if so please someone help.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is the correct approach

Comment: Or should I need to assign CLK pin of oscillator to XTAL1 input of first AT89C2051 and then XTAL2 pin of first IC to remaining 2 IC's XTAL2 pin ( as per crystal connection shown in first image ) ...

Comment: If you think I've missed something, then try it your way and find out for yourself.

Comment: @ EM Fields, Thanks for your comment .... Dear, I need right way to add crystal and design board... I am confused so I am asking :)